# @ in filename using Maxscript

Tags: string-literals, maxscript

Using Maxsctipt: Exporting a file the following code works fine:

```
caption:"Caption" \
types:"text(*.txt)|*.txt|All|*.*|" \
filename:(sysinfo.currentdir + @"\some_text.txt")
```

I am wondering what the significance the @ symbol has?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the maxscript help file:

http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-7F17449E-C377-445C-AC15-CD3BA88A975B.htm,topicNumber=d30e141051

> **Verbatim String Literals**
>
> Verbatim string literals added to MAXScript in 3ds Max 2008 are
> prefixed by the '@' character and are NOT expanded even if containing
> backslash escape character sequences like '\t', '\n' or '\r'.

Bottomline you don't need to escape characters in the string if there are any "illegal" characters in it, especially helpful when dealing with paths loads of \ 's

Comment: Thanks - not knowing the technical name for the thingy that I was looking up ie String literals, searching the help for @ symbol just gave rise to "Help cannot search for that phrase".

Comment: Maxscript helpfile can be your friend and foe at the same time.